# Error — PG::InvalidParameterValue: ERROR: invalid value for parameter "client_min_messages": "panic"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pg, macos-catalina

I'm having issues getting a ruby on rails project running with Docker. I have a hunch it has something to do with running macOS Catalina (10.15.1). The issue comes when I try to `docker-compose run web rake db:create`.

When I run `docker-compose run web rake db:create` I get this output:

```
Starting vft_db_1 ... done
PG::InvalidParameterValue: ERROR:  invalid value for parameter "client_min_messages": "panic"
HINT:  Available values: debug5, debug4, debug3, debug2, debug1, log, notice, warning, error.
: SET client_min_messages TO 'panic'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:155:in `async_exec'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-
...
Couldn't create database for {"adapter"=>"postgresql", "encoding"=>"unicode", "host"=>"db", "username"=>"postgres", "password"=>nil, "pool"=>5, "database"=>"vft_test", "client_min_messages"=>"warning"}
```

Here is my `database.yml`

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  host: db
  username: postgres
  password:
  pool: 5

development:
  <<: *default
  database: vft_development
  min_messages: warning

test:
  <<: *default
  database: vft_test
  min_messages: warning
```

(I also tried `client_min_messages: warning` but encountered the same issue)

And when I run `$ docker version` I get:

```
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           19.03.5
 API version:       1.40
 Go version:        go1.12.12
 Git commit:        633a0ea
 Built:             Wed Nov 13 07:22:34 2019
 OS/Arch:           darwin/amd64
 Experimental:      false

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          19.03.5
  API version:      1.40 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.12.12
  Git commit:       633a0ea
  Built:            Wed Nov 13 07:29:19 2019
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          v1.2.10
  GitCommit:        b34a5c8af56e510852c35414db4c1f4fa6172339
 runc:
  Version:          1.0.0-rc8+dev
  GitCommit:        3e425f80a8c931f88e6d94a8c831b9d5aa481657
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.18.0
  GitCommit:        fec3683
```

Thanks!

Comment: Have you solved this? I'm getting this exact same error on Heroku.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be related to **PostgreSQL 12**.
[Here a post explaining it](https://nrogap.medium.com/old-rails-and-postgresql-12-problem-ba44388feb1d), it suggests several ways to fix it.

I personally used a lower version of PostgreSQL to get rid of it.
Lazy but did the job for me :)